# SQL Server : executing stored procedure problems

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to execute a stored procedure I keep getting an error:

> Procedure or function 'dynamictable' expects parameter '@tablename', which was not supplied

Can you please fix my code?

```
conn.Open();    
SqlCommand search = new SqlCommand("dbo.dynamictable", conn);
search.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
search.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tablename", table));
search.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("width", housewidth.ToString()));
```

Here is the query if it may help you help me:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dynamictable
    (@tablename nvarchar(100), @width nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

    SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM [' + @tablename+ '] WHERE [Width] = '+ @width;

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
END
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: I must question the number of tables that have a column named width. This approach has a [XY problem smell](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

If `table` is null then you will get that message.

You should really be specifying the type and size of the parameter:

```cs
search.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tablename", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = table;
search.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@width", SqlDbType.Int).value = housewidth;
```

Your current query is also at risk of SQL injection. It should be using proper parameterization and escaping even in the dynamic part:

```sql
CREATE procedure dynamictable
    (@tablename nvarchar(128), @width int)
as
begin

declare @SQL nvarchar(max) =
N'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tablename) + ' WHERE [Width] = @width;';
exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@width int', @width = @width;

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "@" from parameter name when passing it over

```
search.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("tablename", table));
```

Comment: I tried your way and it still return the same error

Comment: @ThanhLamChi try to update the command as you would run it on sq-server. e.g
SqlCommand("exec dbo.dynamictable (at)tablename, (at)width", conn);

Answer (score 0):

> 'Procedure or function 'dynamictable' expects parameter '@tablename', which was not supplied.'

That error typically means the C# variable called `table` is null. Your stored procedure does not seem to have any relevant issues. (And you're mentioning '@' which is extra - so technically, tablename is not set yet.. (: )